# Temporarily disable auto_now / auto_now_add

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a model like this:

```
class FooBar(models.Model):
    createtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    lastupdatetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I want to overwrite the two date fields for some model instances (used when migrating data). The current solution looks like this:

```
for field in new_entry._meta.local_fields:
    if field.name == "lastupdatetime":
        field.auto_now = False
    elif field.name == "createtime":
        field.auto_now_add = False

new_entry.createtime = date
new_entry.lastupdatetime = date
new_entry.save()

for field in new_entry._meta.local_fields:
    if field.name == "lastupdatetime":
        field.auto_now = True
    elif field.name == "createtime":
        field.auto_now_add = True
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: new_entry.createtime.auto_now = False ?

Comment: +1 - This would be really nice for testing

Comment: @akonsu Nope: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'auto_now'

Comment: It's worth pointing out that more than a few core devs [are in favor of deprecating `auto_now(_add)`](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22995)

Comment: new_entry._meta.get_field('date_update') is more direct

Comment: @Sérgio this isn't more direct, it's the way to alter the field definition. Accesing to the model attribute (new_entry.createtime.auto_now) you're getting the attribute value, not the field definition.

Answer (score 138):

I've recently faced this situation while testing my application. I needed to "force" an expired timestamp. In my case, I did the trick by using a queryset update. Like this:

```py
# my model
class FooBar(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)


# my tests
foo = FooBar.objects.get(pk=1)
    
# force a timestamp
lastweek = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
FooBar.objects.filter(pk=foo.pk).update(updated_at=lastweek)

# do the testing.
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Here are the docs for update(): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update

Comment: Actually, this method works pretty well if you don't mind hitting the database. I ended up using this for tests as well.

Comment: from Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once Be aware that the update() method is converted directly to an SQL statement. It is a bulk operation for direct updates. It doesn’t run any save() methods on your models, or emit the pre_save or post_save signals (which are a consequence of calling save()), or honor the auto_now field option

Comment: @NoamG I think this is a rare case where this `update()` behaviour is exactly what we need.

Answer (score 61):

You can't really disable auto_now/auto_now_add in another way than you already do. If you need the flexibility to change those values, `auto_now`/`auto_now_add` is not best choice. It is often more flexible to use `default` and/or override the `save()` method to do manipulation right before the object is saved.

Using `default` and an overridden `save()` method, one way to solve your problem would be to define your model like this:

```
class FooBar(models.Model):
    createtime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    lastupdatetime = models.DateTimeField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not kwargs.pop('skip_lastupdatetime', False):
            self.lastupdatetime = datetime.datetime.now()

        super(FooBar, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

In your code, where you want to skip the automatic lastupdatetime change, just use

```
new_entry.save(skip_lastupdatetime=True)
```

If your object is saved in the admin interface or other places, save() will be called without the skip_lastupdatetime argument, and it will behave just as it did before with `auto_now`.

Comment: TL;DR Don't use `auto_now_add` use `default` instead.

Comment: One caveat to this example is that `datetime.datetime.now` returns a naive datetime. To use a timezone-aware datetime, use `from django.utils import timezone` and `models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)` see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects

Comment: So, just to be clear: If you only want to be able to modify the `createtime` field, you don't need to override `save()`. It is sufficient to replace `auto_now_add=True` by the equivalent `default=timezone.now, editable=False, blank=True` (according to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add)). The latter two options ensure similar behavior in the admin.

Answer (score 55):

You can also use the `update_fields` parameter of `save()` and pass your `auto_now` fields. Here's an example:

```py
# Date you want to force
new_created_date = date(year=2019, month=1, day=1)

# The `created` field is `auto_now` in your model
instance.created = new_created_date
instance.save(update_fields=['created'])
```

Here's the explanation from Django's documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save

Comment: I wish I could vote this higher!  This is really what I wanted (to alter parts of the model without touching the 'auto' fields), but unfortunately doesn't answer the question given (which is to save explicit values to the fields using `auto_now` and `auto_now_add`).

Comment: best answer, I wish I can give it 10 votes, very simple and elegant

Comment: object has to be first created. otherwise get this error Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key

Comment: Apparently this requires a somewhat recent version of Django, unlike the unsupported one I'm required to use.

Comment: This as introduced in Django 1.5 in 2013, so I hope you can use something newer than that or you are in big trouble :D

Comment: While this will work for an `auto_now_add` field, this does not address how to update an `auto_now` field. The `DateTimeField.pre_save` method still runs, and overrides the field to the current time.

Answer (score 30):

I used the suggestion made by the asker, and created some functions.  Here is the use case:

```
turn_off_auto_now(FooBar, "lastupdatetime")
turn_off_auto_now_add(FooBar, "createtime")

new_entry.createtime = date
new_entry.lastupdatetime = date
new_entry.save()
```

Here's the implementation:

```
def turn_off_auto_now(ModelClass, field_name):
    def auto_now_off(field):
        field.auto_now = False
    do_to_model(ModelClass, field_name, auto_now_off)

def turn_off_auto_now_add(ModelClass, field_name):
    def auto_now_add_off(field):
        field.auto_now_add = False
    do_to_model(ModelClass, field_name, auto_now_add_off)

def do_to_model(ModelClass, field_name, func):
    field = ModelClass._meta.get_field_by_name(field_name)[0]
    func(field)
```

Similar functions can be created to turn them back on.

Comment: In most cases instead of iteration you could probably just do `Clazz._meta.get_field_by_name(field_name)[0]`.

Comment: Thanks @naktinis. Changed.

Comment: n.b. (1.10) ModelClass._meta.get_field_by_name(field_name)[0] in do_to_model didn't seem to be working for me - changed to: ModelClass._meta.get_field(field_name)

Answer (score 26):

I went the context manager way for reusability.

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def suppress_autotime(model, fields):
    _original_values = {}
    for field in model._meta.local_fields:
        if field.name in fields:
            _original_values[field.name] = {
                'auto_now': field.auto_now,
                'auto_now_add': field.auto_now_add,
            }
            field.auto_now = False
            field.auto_now_add = False
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        for field in model._meta.local_fields:
            if field.name in fields:
                field.auto_now = _original_values[field.name]['auto_now']
                field.auto_now_add = _original_values[field.name]['auto_now_add']
```

Use like so:

```
with suppress_autotime(my_object, ['updated']):
    my_object.some_field = some_value
    my_object.save()
```

Boom.

Comment: looks good! But if I get it right, you send the object and not the model, and usually 'auto_now_add' field will be set upon creation, so isn't it too late to change it?

Comment: @user2880391 the context manager in the answer works as you want, it's just that the example is showing an update on an `auto_now` field. If you instead put a `FooBar.objects.create(...)` inside the context block, with `createtime` as the field name to suppress, then the `auto_now_add should be suppressed successfully

Answer (score 13):

For those looking at this when they are writing tests, there is a python library called [freezegun](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun) which allows you to fake the time - so when the `auto_now_add` code runs, it gets the time you actually want.  So:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from freezegun import freeze_time

with freeze_time('2016-10-10'):
    new_entry = FooBar.objects.create(...)
with freeze_time('2016-10-17'):
    # use new_entry as you wish, as though it was created 7 days ago
```

It can also be used as a decorator - see the link above for basic docs.

Answer (score 6):

You can override `auto_now_add` without special code.

I came across this question when I tried to create an object with particular date:

```
Post.objects.create(publication_date=date, ...)
```

where `publication_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)`.

So this is what I've done:

```
post = Post.objects.create(...)
post.publication_date = date
post.save()
```

This has successfully overridden `auto_now_add`.

As a more long-term solution, overriding `save` method is the way to go: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16583

Answer (score 3):

A bit more clean version of context manager from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35943149/1731460

**NOTE:** Do NOT use this context manager in your views/forms or anywhere in your Django app.
This context manager alter internal state of field (by temporarily setting auto_now and auto_now_add to False).
That will cause Django to not populate these fields with timezone.now() during execution of context
manager's body for concurrent requests (ie. same process, different thread).

Although this can be used for standalone scripts (ex. management commands, data migration)
which are **not run in the same process** with Django app.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def suppress_auto_now(model, field_names=None):
    """
    Temp disable auto_now and auto_now_add for django fields
    @model - model class or instance
    @field_names - list of field names to suppress or all model's
                   fields that support auto_now_add, auto_now"""

    def get_auto_now_fields(user_selected_fields):
        for field in model._meta.get_fields():
            field_name = field.name
            if user_selected_fields and field_name not in user_selected_fields:
                continue
            if hasattr(field, 'auto_now') or hasattr(field, 'auto_now_add'):
                yield field

    fields_state = {}

    for field in get_auto_now_fields(user_selected_fields=field_names):
        fields_state[field] = {
            'auto_now': field.auto_now, 
            'auto_now_add': field.auto_now_add
        }

    for field in fields_state:
        field.auto_now = False
        field.auto_now_add = False
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        for field, state in fields_state.items():
            field.auto_now = state['auto_now']
            field.auto_now_add = state['auto_now_add']
```

You can use it even with Factories (factory-boy)

```
with suppress_auto_now(Click, ['created']):
    ClickFactory.bulk_create(post=obj.post, link=obj.link, created__iter=created)
```

Answer (score 3):

From django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#datefield)

#### DateField.auto_now_add

Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created. Useful for creation of timestamps. Note that the current date is always used; **it’s not just a default value that you can override**. So even if you set a value for this field when creating the object, it will be ignored. **If you want to be able to modify this field, set the following instead of `auto_now_add=True`**:

For *DateField*: `default=date.today` - from datetime.date.today()

For DateTimeField: `default=timezone.now` - from django.utils.timezone.now()

Answer (score 2):

I needed to disable auto_now for a DateTime field during a migration and was able to do this.

```
events = Events.objects.all()
for event in events:
    for field in event._meta.fields:
        if field.name == 'created_date':
            field.auto_now = False
    event.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm late to the party, but similar to several of the other answers, this is a solution I used during a database migration. The difference from the other answers is that this disables **all** auto_now fields for the model under the assumption that there's really no reason to have more than one such field.

```
def disable_auto_now_fields(*models):
    """Turns off the auto_now and auto_now_add attributes on a Model's fields,
    so that an instance of the Model can be saved with a custom value.
    """
    for model in models:
        for field in model._meta.local_fields:
            if hasattr(field, 'auto_now'):
                field.auto_now = False
            if hasattr(field, 'auto_now_add'):
                field.auto_now_add = False
```

Then to use it, you can simply do:

```
disable_auto_now_fields(Document, Event, ...)
```

And it will go through and nuke all of your `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` fields for all of the model classes you pass in.

Answer (score 1):

While not exactly an answer (the question mentions data migration), here is an approach for testing with [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org).

Basically, it is possible to define a fixture to [monkeypatch](https://docs.pytest.org/how-to/monkeypatch.html) certain field instance attributes. Example may be adapted to loop through fields, etc.

```
@pytest.fixture
def disable_model_auto_dates(monkeypatch):
    """Disables auto dates on SomeModel."""
    # might be local, might be on top
    from project.models import SomeModel

    field = SomeModel._meta.get_field('created_at')
    monkeypatch.setattr(field, 'auto_now', False)
    monkeypatch.setattr(field, 'auto_now_add', False)
```

Answer (score 0):

copy of [Django - Models.DateTimeField - Changing dynamically auto_now_add value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39883335/django-models-datetimefield-changing-dynamically-auto-now-add-value/45946742#45946742)

Well , I spent this afternoon find out and the first problem is how fetch model object and where in code . I'm in restframework in serializer.py , for example in `__init__` of serializer it could not have the Model yet . Now in to_internal_value you can get the model class , after get the Field and after modify the field properties like in this example :

```
class ProblemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def to_internal_value(self, data): 
        ModelClass = self.Meta.model
        dfil = ModelClass._meta.get_field('date_update')
        dfil.auto_now = False
        dfil.editable = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed solution that will work with `update_or_create`, I've came to this solution based on @andreaspelme code.

Only change is that You can set skipping by setting modified field to `skip` not only by actually passing kwarg `skip_modified_update` to save() method.

Just `yourmodelobject.modified='skip'` and update will be skipped!

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class TimeTrackableAbstractModel(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, db_index=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        skip_modified_update = kwargs.pop('skip_modified_update', False)
        if skip_modified_update or self.modified == 'skip':
            self.modified = models.F('modified')
        else:
            self.modified = timezone.now()
        super(TimeTrackableAbstractModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variation and simplification of the useful answer from @soulseekah https://stackoverflow.com/a/35943149/202168

This one can suppress fields on multiple models simultaneously - useful in conjunction with `factory_boy` such as when you have a SubFactory that also has fields that need suppressing

It looks like:

```py
@contextmanager
def suppress_autonow(*fields: DeferredAttribute):
    _original_values = {}
    for deferred_attr in fields:
        field = deferred_attr.field
        _original_values[field] = {
            'auto_now': field.auto_now,
            'auto_now_add': field.auto_now_add,
        }
        field.auto_now = False
        field.auto_now_add = False
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        for field, values in _original_values.items():
            field.auto_now = values['auto_now']
            field.auto_now_add = values['auto_now_add']
```

And is used like (with `factory_boy`):

```py
with suppress_autonow(Comment.created_at, Post.created_at):
    PostFactory.create_batch(10)  # if e.g. PostFactory also creates Comments
```

or just Django:

```py
with suppress_autonow(FooBar.createtime, FooBar.lastupdatetime):
    foobar = FooBar(
        createtime=datetime(2013, 4, 6),
        lastupdatetime=datetime(2016, 7, 9),
    )
    foobar.save()
```

i.e. you pass in the actual fields you want to suppress.

Note that you must pass them as class fields (i.e. `Comment.created_at`) and not instance fields (not `my_comment.created_at`)

NOTE:
This will break if you pass non-Date/DateTime/Time field to the `fields` args. if it bothers you, add in an extra `isinstance` check after `field = deferred_attr.field`