# Django model - Updating a attribute without touching lastmodified_at

Tags: python, django, django-models, timestamp

I'm creating a small wiki app and use a lastmodified_at attribute (`auto_now`). Now I'd like to count the view of my pages.

My first thought was to add a field to my wiki article object and incarnate it by one if the `showArticle` view is called.

Unfortunately this would cause the `lastmodified_at` to be updated as well.

Is there another possibility then create an extra table which contains the article_id and the counter or to remove/rebuild my `auto_now` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be tempted to have a separate model to track page views with an FK to your article model.

e.g.

```
class ArticleViewCount(model):
    counter = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    article = models.OneToOneField(Article)
```

Then you can call the page count from the template using the articles related field

Answer (score 0):

there are several answers already:

for example, don't use auto_now directly, override the save
or change field's auto_now property before saving.

[Temporarily disable auto_now / auto_now_add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499767/temporarily-disable-auto-now-auto-now-add)

I will provide another dirty method if you like to keep the auto_now:

```
class Temp(models.Model):
    test = models.CharField(max_length=255)       
    updated = models.DateTimeFeild(auto_now=True)

    def save_without_updated(self):
        self._meta.get_field("updated").auto_now = False
        # self.meta.auto_created = False
        self.save()
        # self.meta.auto_created = True
        self._meta.get_field("updated").auto_now = True
```