# Django - Populate DateTime field from other DateTimeField set with auto_now

Tags: django

I'm trying to populate a `last_version_date` from a `modified` field set with `auto_now`. In my save method, if a new version is created i want to save the modified date for that record.

Simplified example :

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    version = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=1)
    last_version_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=False)

    def save(self, keep_history=False, *args, **kwargs):    
        if keep_history:
            self.last_version_date = self.modified
            self.version = self.version + 1

        return super(Poll, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Usage

```
>>> p = Poll.objects.create(question = 'Test1')
>>> p.save()
>>> p.modified
datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 18, 6, 50, 41, 820000, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> p.last_version_date
datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 18, 6, 50, 38, 381000, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> p.created
datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 18, 6, 50, 38, 380000, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>>
>>>
>>> p.save(True)
>>> p.modified
datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 18, 6, 51, 1, 804000, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> p.last_version_date
datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 18, 6, 50, 41, 820000, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Notice how in the second save the `last_version_date` is being updated with the previous value of `modified`.

Looking at the source for `DateTimeField`'s `auto_now` option i see it's being populated in the `pre_save` hook so I would expect the value to be populated prior to the save.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From django documentation :

> **DateField.auto_now_add**
>
> Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created. Useful for creation of timestamps. Note that
> the current date is always used; **it’s not just a default value that
> you can override.**

If you want to have a default time value of your 'last_version_date' use 'default' key with a timezone.now function as input

```
from django.utils import timezone
class Poll(models.Model):
    ....
    last_version_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,blank=False)
```

See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499767/temporarily-disable-auto-now-auto-now-add).
Your save function can become

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    keep_history = kwargs.get('keep_history', False)   
    if keep_history:
        self.last_version_date = self.modified
        self.version = self.version + 1
```

and use it as following

```
>>> p.save(keep_history=True)
```

You can also use, from concurrency, an **IntegerVersionField** for your version field.

Comment: Your missing the point. I don't want `last_version_date` to always equal `modified` - only if `keep_history=True` i want to retrieve the value of `modified` and save it into `last_version_date`. I need them to be exactly the same.

Comment: You can keep your save code as is ... my advice is just replace auto_now_add with default. You can simulate a auto_new_add with a default equal to timezone.now. That's all.