# Django - Models.DateTimeField - Changing dynamically auto_now_add value

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django model with a DateTimeField where auto_now_add is set to True. This works well.

```
class Problem(models.Model):
    ...
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('created on', auto_now_add=True)
```

I would like, when I create test data or when I load historical data, to **bypass** this paramater (auto_now_add set to False) to set the date as I want and **switch back** to the standard behaviour (auto_now_add set to True).

Is there a way to **dynamically** change the class (by changing attribute of the class ?). This parameter has no impact on the database and is probably triggered during the save phase.

I don't want :-)

```
date_created = models.DateTimeField('created on', default=timezone.now)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you can just explicitly pass `date_created` value when creating your data and `auto_now_add` will be ignored. In case you want that column to be `NULL` you can pass `None`

Comment: and why not default=timezone.now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar problem when importing data from another application by means of a data import script being executed from the shell command.
Since it isn't possible to disable dynamically the auto_now_add or the auto_now feature, I had to use a modified settings module.

First, defined an IMPORT variable in the original settings module:

```
IMPORT = False
```

and created a new import_settings module containing only:

```
from my_app.settings import *
IMPORT = True
```

Then, in defining my models, I added the code

```
from django.conf import settings
if settings.IMPORT:
    AUTO_NOW = False
else:
    AUTO_NOW = True
```

and used the value of AUTO_NOW in configuring the DateTimeField

```
created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, null=True, blank=True, auto_now_add=AUTO_NOW)
modified = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, null=True, blank=True, auto_now=AUTO_NOW)
```

Finally, I launched the data import script using the --settings option of the manage command:

```
python manage.py shell --settings=my_app.import_settings
```

Answer (score 0):

Well , I spent this afternoon find out and the first problem is how fetch model object and where in code . I'm in restframework in serializer.py , for example in `__init__` of serializer it could not have the Model yet . Now in to_internal_value you can get the model class , after get the Field and after modify the field properties like in this example :

```
class ProblemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def to_internal_value(self, data): 
        ModelClass = self.Meta.model
        dfil = ModelClass._meta.get_field('date_update')
        dfil.auto_now = False
        dfil.editable = True
```