# Bulk create auto fields in Django

Tags: python, django

I have two models and I want to migrate all data from one to another. For simulating the problem, suppose the models below:

```
from django.db import models

class Book:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class BookArchived:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The code for migrations is:

```
book_objs = []
for archived_book in BookArchived.objects.all():
    book_objs.append(Book(name=archived_book.name, is_archived=True, created_at=archived_book.created_at))

Book.objects.bulk_create(book_objs)
```

The problem with this code is that, although I explicitly set `created_at` field (`created_at=archived_book.created_at`), Django inserts all of them with current time.

I know that if `pk` field is explicitly set (`id=archived_book.id`), new objects will preserve original timestamps. But there is already overlapping IDs in database, so this approach will create another problem. How can I preserve original `created_at` values for `BookArchived` instances?

Comment: @blondelg: that is all the case.

Comment: I do not understand why you need an extra model. You have a boolean that determines if the `Book` `is_archived`, thus you can easily extract the books that are archived.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it is legacy model. Now data lives in two different tables. That's why I want to migrate all data from `BookArchived` to `Book` and then delete the former model.

Comment: @ElginCahangirov you will need to remove the `auto_now_add=True` from the `Book` model migrate first and add it back later in another migration. `auto_now_add` implicitly sets `editable=False` so you can't set it's value yourself.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat not acceptable solution for production environment. At the time of deploy there'll be inserts to book table (`Book` model)

Comment: @ElginCahangirov I am not talking about not having `auto_now_add` completely. You need to to this in multiple migrations since `auto_now_add` would prevent you from setting any value on the field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this gem https://stackoverflow.com/a/59898220/519995 which should work, but I haven't tested it myself.

```python
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def suppress_auto_now(model, field_names):
    """
    From https://stackoverflow.com/a/59898220/519995
    idea taken here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35943149/1731460
    """
    fields_state = {}
    for field_name in field_names:
        field = model._meta.get_field(field_name)
        fields_state[field] = {'auto_now': field.auto_now, 'auto_now_add': field.auto_now_add}

    for field in fields_state:
        field.auto_now = False
        field.auto_now_add = False
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        for field, state in fields_state.items():
            field.auto_now = state['auto_now']
            field.auto_now_add = state['auto_now_add']
```

Use it like this:

```
with suppress_autotime(Book, ['created_at']):
        Book.objects.bulk_create(book_objs)
```

**NOTE:**
Do NOT use this context manager in your views/forms or anywhere in your Django app. This context manager alter internal state of field (by temporarily setting `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` to `False`). That will cause Django to not populate these fields with `timezone.now()` during execution of context manager's body for concurrent requests (ie. same process, different thread). Although this can be used for standalone scripts (ex. management commands, data migration) which are not run in the same process with Django app.

Comment: this solutions works as expected in this case. But I think this is dangerous to use in view/form or anywhere in project, since the context manager is altering internal state of field of model. This change will have effect on the whole process that runs django app, so field won't be autofilled by django on save between enter and exit time from context manager. What do you think?

Comment: I tested this code in django view. As I supposed, it caused error for concurrent requests that try to create new `Book` instance, since `suppress_auto_now` context manager altering state of `created_at` field. So using this code in django app is **not safe**, although it fits to my needs. I will run migration code in django management command that will be executed in a separate process from django app.

Comment: please accept my edit, for marking your answer as accepted.

Comment: You are right @ElginCahangirov !    This is truly dangerous if used inside the webserver, I was only thinking about a data migration script that is run outside of the server processes.


 - edit accepted, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As per a note in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#datefield) of the `DateField`:

> As currently implemented, setting auto_now or auto_now_add to True
> will cause the field to have editable=False and blank=True set.

Since `editable` will be set to `False` you providing any value to the model will not work. You will need to do this step in multiple migrations.

Firstly have the model without `auto_now_add`:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

Generate a migration for this using `python manage.py makemigrations`. Next we want to do a [data migration [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations). First run `python manage.py makemigrations --empty <yourappname>` this will create an empty migration which you will edit to copy data from `BookArchived` to `Book`. This would look something like:

```
from django.db import migrations

def copy_legacy_books(apps, schema_editor):
    # We can't import the Person model directly as it may be a newer
    # version than this migration expects. We use the historical version.
    Book = apps.get_model('yourappname', 'Book')
    BookArchived = apps.get_model('yourappname', 'BookArchived')
    book_objs = []
    for archived_book in BookArchived.objects.all():
        book_objs.append(Book(name=archived_book.name, is_archived=True, created_at=archived_book.created_at))
    
    Book.objects.bulk_create(book_objs)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('yourappname', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(copy_legacy_books),
    ]
```

Now after this simply add the `auto_now_add` kwarg to your the date-time field and generate another migration using `python manage.py makemigrations`:

```
class Book:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: thanks for your effort. Solution proposed overcomes my problem. But think about highly concurrent requests to the app. While my custom migration executes `Book.created_at` will not be `auto_now_add` which will lead to server errors.

Comment: @ElginCahangirov how would that cause errors? The server should not even be running before all the migrations are applied. Considering that `python manage.py migrate` is run all these 3 migrations would be applied sequentially, after which you can add some book instances in another data migration if you want or with fixtures (As per your comment "At the time of deploy there'll be inserts to book table"). After all the migrations are done and initial data is loaded is when ideally the server should be run with `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: @ElginCahangirov See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/initial-data/ on how initial data can be provided for models.

Comment: let's suppose that data migration will take 2 minutes (other 2 migrations will take much less of course). During this 2 minutes `created_at` field of `Book` will not be `auto_now_add=True`. So, for requests that try to insert book to database will result in server error (since django will not populate this column, database will complain about not null constraint violation).  As for your saying `server should be run after all the migrations are done and initial data is loaded`, this not the case in ci/cd environments like deploying with kubernetes. Application should be live during deployment.

Comment: @ElginCahangirov that is a bit sketchy though, the initial data part can be left out but the server needs to run even while the migrations are being run? What happens when a table is not yet created then? (I might be wrong here, not very experienced with deployment, etc.)

Comment: generally application is updated after database migrations are over. So new tables don't cause problem, since old app instance is not aware of new model yet. After creation of new table, old application is terminated gracefully, new one is created and requests are now dispatched to the new instance. Django's some behaviors cause problems during CI/CD. See [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/470#comment:30) for example.